# Sharepoint Designer - Workflow With Date Not Null and Null?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am new to Sharepoint Designer, and looking to create a workflow.  The workflow is meant to look at a list, and when one date field is not null (has any date) and another date field is null (does not have a date) I need to alert someone on the team.  I would like to just email this person a link to a view, which will be filtered to the same criteria.

Anyone have any tips, for getting the null and not null?  Also any tips on how to navigate this, would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: Find this question answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176028/check-blank-null-date-in-workflow,  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166866/workflow-test-if-a-value-is-empty

Comment: Thanks, yea. I found you have to set the field to a variable, and then you can check if the variable is empty or not empty.